# DelegateCommand in Grid/ListView

Tags: c#, .net, listview, data-binding, windows-store-apps

Why `DelegateCommand` doesn't work in my `Listview`?

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Command="{Binding OpenCommand}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

But it works when I put my button outside my listview. What I'm doing wrong?

Maybe there is `ListView.ItemCommand Event` in `Windows-Store Apps`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because when you're binding in an `ItemTemplate`, your datacontext is the current item and not the ListView's data context. If you want to use the ListView's datacontext, you can do this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" />
```

Since `AncestorType` isn't available for Windows Store apps, using `ElementName` should work:

```
<ListView Name="myListView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenCommand, ElementName=myListView}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```